# About the usage of if and when

Tags: clojure

In the source of clojure.core:

```
(def meta (fn ^:static meta [x]
            (if (instance? clojure.lang.IMeta x)
              (. ^clojure.lang.IMeta x (meta)))))

(defmacro ^{:private true} assert-args
  [& pairs]
  `(do (when-not ~(first pairs)
         (throw (IllegalArgumentException.
                  (str (first ~'&form) " requires " ~(second pairs) " in " ~'*ns* ":" (:line (meta ~'&form))))))
     ~(let [more (nnext pairs)]
        (when more
          (list* `assert-args more)))))
```

A trivial question. I understand the difference between `if` and `when` (I've read the source of `when`). What I'm trying to understand here is why do they use `when` instead of `if` in the definition of `assert-args`? It seems to me it's ok to use `if` here.